# C++ shared_mutex implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, stdatomic

`boost::shared_mutex` or `std::shared_mutex` (C++17) can be used for single writer, multiple reader access.  As an educational exercise, I put together a simple implementation that uses spinlocking and has other limitations (eg. fairness policy), but is obviously not intended to be used in real applications.

The idea is that the mutex keeps a reference count that is zero if no thread holds the lock. If > 0, the value represents the number of readers that have access. If -1, a single writer has access.

Is this a correct implementation (in particular with the used, minimal, memory orderings) that is free of data races ?

```
#include <atomic>

class my_shared_mutex {
    std::atomic<int> refcount{0};
public:

    void lock() // write lock
    {
        int val;
        do {
            val = 0; // Can only take a write lock when refcount == 0

        } while (!refcount.compare_exchange_weak(val, -1, std::memory_order_acquire));
        // can memory_order_relaxed be used if only a single thread takes write locks ?
    }

    void unlock() // write unlock
    {
        refcount.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void lock_shared() // read lock
    {
        int val;
        do {
            do {
                val = refcount.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

            } while (val == -1); // spinning until the write lock is released

        } while (!refcount.compare_exchange_weak(val, val+1, std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock_shared() // read unlock
    {
        // This must be a release operation (see answer)
        refcount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(CAS = Compare And Swap = C++ `compare_exchange_weak` function, which on x86 will typically compile to an [x86](/questions/tagged/x86)  [`lock cmpxchg` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html) which can only run when it owns the cache line in Exclusive or Modified MESI state).

---

`lock_shared` looks good: spinning read-only attempting a CAS only when it looks possible is better for performance than spinning on CAS or atomic increment.  You already needed to do a read-only check to avoid changing `-1` to `0` and unlocking a write-lock.

On x86, put a `_mm_pause()` in the retry path of the spin loop to avoid memory-order mis-speculation pipeline nukes when exiting the read-only spin loop, and steal fewer resources from the other hyperthread while spinning.  (Use a `while()` loop, not `do{}while()`, so the pause only runs after failing once.  `pause` on Skylake and later waits about 100 cycles so avoid it in the fast-path.)

---

**I think `unlock_shared` should be using `mo_release`, not `mo_relaxed`**, since it needs to order the loads from the shared data structure to make sure a writer doesn't start writing before the loads from the reader critical section happen.  ([LoadStore reordering](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) is a thing on weakly-ordered architectures, even though x86 only does StoreLoad reordering.)  [A Release operation will order preceding loads and keep them inside the critical section](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

---

> (in write `lock`): // can memory_order_relaxed be used if only a single thread takes write locks ?

No, you still need to keep the writes inside the critical section, so the CAS still needs to Synchronize With (in C++ terminology) release-stores from `unlock_shared`.

https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ has a nice image that shows the 1-way barrier effect of a release-store or acquire-load.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the memory order in unlock_shared, but my reasoning was that it does not really 'release' anything since it has read-only access and cannot change the data it protects

Comment: @LWimsey: yeah, it's harder to think about load ordering than store ordering, but it's a real thing.  A load becomes globally visible at the moment when it reads data from L1 cache.  (Because that's when it makes a copy from globally-coherent cache into the out-of-order core of a single CPU.)

Comment: @LWimsey Are you saying that lock_shared could immediately do an unlock operation? Crazy, but you seem to imply that ordering WRT to unlock_shared doesn't matter...

Comment: @curiousguy `lock_shared` cannot unlock the shared mutex; It can only take a read-lock if already in unlocked state. You are right about the ordering in `unlock_shared`, that definitively has to be a release operation.

Comment: "_when the value is_" is what?